Rails 7 asset pipeline and font variables
A habit is to define a set of root variables to establish consistency across an application, i.e.
:root {
  --main-font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
  --kbd-font-family: Consolas, "Liberation Mono", Courier, monospace;
  --main-font-color: #000;
  --secondary-font-color: #000;
  --cursive-font-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.93);
  --main_bg_color: #78903a;
}

However this practice appears to require some serious wrangling as the Rails guide does not even mention the word 'font'...
Various attempts are attempted, but never seem to register as the browser sees the font is defined by a variable but only refers to the variable's litteral text and does not offer a preview of the font (indicating it is not loaded)
config.application.rb was set to
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")
and server restarted (although this should not be necessary in development)
so, assuming a family and the files under assets/fonts,
@font-face {
 font-family: 'Gabarito';
 src: url('Gabarito-Regular.ttf'),
      url('Gabarito-Bold.ttf');
 font-display: fallback;
}

how can the root variables be set properly?

Why would the Rails guides mention fonts? It's just CSS and you should handle it the same way you would with any other CSS/assets. If you need to interpolate the path to the assets in your CSS you either pass it through ERB or SASS. Sass Rails has a set of helper methods for this.

suggestion appreciated.  But I'd rather rely on pure CSS (I see little point in learning/memorising additional syntaxic rules over the huge scope CSS already provides)

The resolution was via an insert to the config/assets.rb file
 Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")
and declaring in a css declaration via ruby interpolation for the path
@font-face {
 font-family: 'Gabarito';
 src: url('<%= asset_path('fonts/Gabarito-Regular.ttf') %>')  format("ttf");
      url('<%= asset_path('fonts/Gabarito-Bold.ttf') %>')  format("ttf");
 font-display: fallback;
}

which then allows
:root {
  --main_font_family: Gabarito, sans-serif;
...

